# Getting elements in div tag inline

Tags: php, html, inline, division

The following php script is used to retrieve data from the database and display in a web page! i have used div tags but don't know how to display them inline how can i do that?

```
<?php
                require("includes/db.php");

                $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ";
                $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);


    echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
    echo "Order No.";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
    echo "NIC no";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
    echo "Delivery/Pickup";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
    echo "Address";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
    echo "Expect time";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
    echo "Telephone";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
    echo "Email";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:100px'>";
    echo "Prescription-1";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:100px'>";
    echo "Prescription-2";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div style='width:100px'>";
    echo "Prescriptions-3";
    echo"</div>";



    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

       echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
        echo $row["OrderNo."];
         echo"</div>";
          echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
        echo $row["NIC"];
         echo"</div>";
          echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
        echo $row["DP"];
         echo"</div>";
          echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
        echo $row["Address"];
         echo"</div>";
          echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
        echo $row["DPTime"];
         echo"</div>";
          echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
        echo $row["Telephone"];
         echo"</div>";
          echo"<div style='width:50px'>";
        echo $row["Email"];
         echo"</div>";
         echo"<div style='width:100px'>";
       echo '<a href='.( $row['Image1'] ).' >';
       echo "<img src='" .$row['Image1']. "' height='200' width='200'/>";
        echo "</a>";
         echo"</div>";


       echo"<div style='width:100px'>";
       echo '<a href='.( $row['Image1'] ).' >';
       echo "<img src='" .$row['Image1']. "' height='200' width='200'/>";
        echo "</a>";
         echo"</div>";

       echo"<div style='width:100px'>";
       echo '<a href='.( $row['Image1'] ).' >';
       echo "<img src='" .$row['Image1']. "' height='200' width='200'/>";
        echo "</a>";
         echo"</div>";
    }
       ?>
```

Also i want to display the set of lines after  the while loop in a separate line! how can i do them?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how to display them inline" ?

Comment: use `css` to set the appropriate conditions - float, clear etc

Comment: Did you TRY and google? This is a very common thing, try searching for the CSS property called `display`

Comment: they come one after the other when displayed i want them to happen in the same line!(like a table row)

Comment: some strange layout here - you specify a width for the div or 100px but add an image with a defined with/height of 200px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive the layout you want by using suitable container elements with designated CSS styles as the example below. The layout breaks however because of the explicit size of the images being twice the width assigned to the parent divs - perhaps it would be easier to control the size of the images with CSS also.

```
<style type='text/css'>
    #headers,
    .row{
        width:auto;
        float:left;
        clear:both;
        display:block;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        font-size:0.7rem;
    }
    #headers > div{
        background:black;
        color:white;
    }
    #headers > div,
    .row > div {
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px dotted black;
        clear:none;
        float:left;
        margin:0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        width:50px;
        height:1.5rem;
    }
    .w100{width:100px;}
</style>


<?php
    require("includes/db.php");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);


    echo"
    <div id='headers'>
        <div>Order No.</div>
        <div>NIC no</div>
        <div>Delivery/Pickup</div>
        <div>Address</div>
        <div>Expect time</div>
        <div>Telephone</div>
        <div>Email</div>
        <div class='w100'>Prescription-1</div>
        <div class='w100'>Prescription-2</div>
        <div class='w100'>Prescriptions-3</div>
    </div>";



    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){

        echo"
        <div class='row'>
            <div>{$row['OrderNo.']}</div>
            <div>{$row['NIC']}</div>
            <div>{$row['DP']}</div>
            <div>{$row['Address']}</div>
            <div>{$row['DPTime']}</div>'
            <div>{$row['Telephone']}</div>
            <div>{$row['Email']}</div>
            <div class='w100'>
                <a href='{$row['Image1']}' >
                    <img src='{$row['Image1']}' height='200' width='200'/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='w100'>
                <a href='{$row['Image1']}' >
                    <img src='{$row['Image1']}' height='200' width='200'/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='w100'>
                <a href='{$row['Image1']}'>
                    <img src='{$row['Image1']}' height='200' width='200'/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<table>` tags for your result instead of divs. Each loop will be `<tr>` and values will be `<td>`.